# Change s:VGroup height when child.visible set to false

Tags: apache-flex

I have a code similar to this:

```
<s:VGroup>
    <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:Label text="label" />
        <s:TextInput id="rmName"/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <mx:HorizontalList id="imagePreview" width="100%" visible="false"
                           columnWidth="100" rowCount="1" rowHeight="130" selectable="false" borderVisible="false">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                    ...
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:HorizontalList>
<s:VGroup>
```

I want that the s:VGroup container has the height only of its visible children.
In this example there is a free space even the visibility mx:HorizontalList is set to false. Every time I change the visibility of the child element I want that the parent (s:VGroup) will change his height. How to do this in flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you change the visible attribute from true to false also change the includeInLayout attribute from true to false.